# How to stop a tornado from hitting a major city...

Tags: weather

[image]

There are many of ways this could have been stopped. I want to hear your answers.....

Comment: Don't build cities in tornado prone areas

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how this site works. Currently you don't really provide any information about the scenario you are working on. How big is your major city? Could you make a comparison with an existing one? Are we assuming normal science on an earth-like planet? The most important points is that you don't really provide any criteria for a good answer. You write that there are many ways, but you don't show what your research exactly already revealed and what you want - zero casualties? Please [edit] your question. Have fun on the site

Comment: Many ways like what?

Answer (score 3):

Since a tornado is "just" a wind, you need to be able to either (a) stop the wind, or (b) interrupt the formation of the wind pattern we call a tornado.

Since a tornado is not a "thing" in the same sense as a rock or a bomb, it is merely a pattern of gas flow, it's not like you can easily break it up. If you chop off bits, it will simply regenerate until the colliding storm systems that formed it run out of differential energy.

Theoretically you could intervene at several phases of the tornado formation to "disarm" the phenomenon.

**Phases of Tornado Development**

There are (crudely) four phases in a tornado's development. [Link](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/environment/a15633/how-a-tornado-forms-in-4-steps/)

1. A warm front and cold front meet, and the warm mass of air is lifted by the cold mass of air.
2. Precipitation that would normally counter the updraft is blown horizontally by shear winds, so the updraft above has nothing to limit its strength. Shear winds of different strengths start to form tubes around the updraft
3. The Tubes formed in step 2 are absorbed into the updraft where they start a general rotation and become a supercell.
4. The supercell tube stretches. As surrounding air moves in to replace what is lifted by the updraft, the tornado forms.

**Interrupting the tornado**

1. Prevent warm and cold fronts from meeting - not likely on a planetary sized body.
2. Prevent shear winds when the warm and cold fronts meet - not likely. You have two continental scale masses of rotating air meeting. That pretty much defines shear winds.
3. Prevent the shear wind tubes from merging - this is air we're talking about. The blast of a tornado feels solid when it hits because the relative velocity of the wind to yourself is high. But the tubes of shear winds have low relative velocity to each other so they mix freely.
4. Prevent air from moving in to replace what was displaced by the updraft - Not likely without a lot of forewarning. Remember tornadoes are weather patterns that form in a chaotic system. While formation is not random, the pattern is too complex to afford reliable prediction.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a tornado, you have to dissipate at least one aspect on the energy driving it. You could in theory divert a tornado by altering its path, but that just means lawsuits from everyone that happened to be on the new path, so I will focus on stopping a tornado.

**Plan A: Prevent it from touching the ground.** 
When you detect a tornado about to touch the ground, drive a truck full of explosive to the touchdown location and detonate it. The disturbance caused by the shock-wave will prevent the tornado from reaching the ground for some time. You may need additional loads of explosives in the case of persistent tornadoes. This method has a few drawbacks (including the fact that a tornado does not have to touch the ground to be dangerous, a common misunderstanding).

**Plan B: Deprive the tornado of the large temperature difference that it needs.**
You will find that it is much easier to warm up the cold -air supply of a tornado that chilling the hot-air supply. To warm up the cold-aid supply you could set of explosives though you might prefer not to use a small nuke, burn a lot of fuel, or divert the output of your microwave solar power satellites to heat up the air.

However, if you prefer cooling the hot-air source, load up airplanes with liquid nitrogen and use crop-dusting style methods to cool the hot air.

**Plan C: Develop force field technology.**
This would allow diversion, by enclosing your city in force fields, or stopping the tornado outright by enclosing it until it dissipates.

**Plan D: Weather control.**
Develop the technology that prevents the thunderstorm systems that generate tornadoes from forming in the first place.

Plan B is actually viable given our current technology, but it would be very expensive as tornado systems are large, energetic events and the scale of the tornado control will necessarily be large and expensive for something that is rarely used. The fact that tornadoes are unpredictable makes it very hard to move the necessary resources in place just in time, so you would have to have a lot of idle resources nearly in place at all times.

Ok, so how big is a tornado really. [According to the NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4489157/) discussing Total Kinetic Energy (TKE):

> TKE is computed for all 8752 tornadoes in the SPC database over the
>   period 2007–2013. There are many more weak tornadoes (EF0) than strong
>   ones (EF2 and higher) so the values are highly skewed with a median
>   TKE of 62.1 gigajoules (GJ) and a interquartile range between 9.1 and
>   383.2 GJ. On a logarithmic scale the distribution is symmetric (Fig 1). Ten percent of the tornadoes over the period have TKE exceeding
>   1.97 terajoules (TJ or 1012 joules), five percent have TKE exceeding 5.53 TJ and one percent have TKE exceeding 31.9 TJ. The tornado with the most energy is the Tallulah-Yazoo City-Durant tornado of April 24,
>   2010 with a TKE of 516.7 TJ. It tracked over 240 km from Louisiana
>   through Mississippi with a width of 2.82 km at its widest. It resulted
>   in ten fatalities and 146 injuries. The most severe damage (EF4)
>   occurred in the Mississippi counties of Yazoo and Holmes.

Note: 1 Watt-hour = 3600 Joules, thus 61.2 GJ=16.9 MWh, 5.53 TJ=1.54GWh and 516.7 TJ=155 GWh